# How to get a logo image to fit its parent with bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this navbar very simple, logo and a couple of links.

The thing is that the image won't fit the parent which has a fixed height.

As you can see the logo with gray background is taller than the div where I want it to fit:

[image: As you can see the logo with gray background is taller than the div where I want it to fit]

```
<nav class="menu-nav container-fluid" style="max-height:50px; background-color:gray;">
    <div class="row ">
        <a href="#" class="logo-img col h-100 ">
           <img src="img/bruke-logo.png" class="mw-100" alt="logobruke">
        </a>

        <div class="col-7 h-100">
              Menu
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 h-100">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-6"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i></div>

                <p class="col-6 text-right mb-0"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.logo-img {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHJvc.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="menu-nav container-fluid" style="max-height:50px; background-color:gray;">
    <div class="row ">
        <a href="#" class="logo-img col">
           
        </a>

        <div class="col-7 h-100">
              Menu
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 h-100">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-6"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i></div>

                <p class="col-6 text-right mb-0"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```